# Azure subscription with a new Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, subscription

I actually have a subscription linked to my company Azure Active Directory, but for security reasons, we are unable to use the AAD from the company.

So, the IT department told us that we can created our own Azure AD within the subscription, but, when I created the new tenant and try to link with the subscription, is not possible for the kind of subscription CSP.

Do you know how to create a AAD within an specific subscription or if it's not possible?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the CSP subscription, but this link should help you a little further on your journey - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory